# How to hide/show input field on user's selection?

Tags: javascript, html

If user selects 'other' ,  the textfield 'specify' should appear, otherwise not.

HTML:

```
    <select id="city">

    <option id="delhi" value="1"> Delhi </option>

    <option id="other" value="2"> - - other - -</option>

    </select>

<input type="text" name="specify" id="specify" size="20" placeholder="specify" class="formfield3"/>
```

I have tried using javascript:

```
window.onload = function() {

 document.getElementById('specify').style.display = 'none';
}

 document.getElementById('city').oninput(function () {

    if (document.getElementById('other').selected) {

        document.getElementById('specify').style.display = 'initial';

    } else {

        document.getElementById('specify').style.display = 'none';
    }
});
```

Comment: Ok. And what have you tried?

Comment: Sorry..I have edited the question just now.

Comment: to me it worked after i put onchange function that do what you done using oninput. Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/4Fa5h/) how you imagined that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  window.onload = function() {
    var input = document.getElementById('specify');
    input.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    var city = document.getElementById('city');
    city.onchange = function () {
      if (city.options[city.selectedIndex].value == 2) {
      input.style.visibility = 'visible';
       } else {
      input.style.visibility = 'hidden';
     }
   }
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/xBW49/)

*side note: if you are going to  access an element multiple times in your script, its better to store a reference to variable. every time you use `document.getElementBy`the `DOM` needs to be traversed again.*

Comment: nthing...looking like you missed to complete brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Add onchange to select

```
<select onchange="changeFunction(this)">
    <option id="delhi" value="1"> Delhi </option>
    <option id="other" value="2"> - - other - -</option>
</select>

<input id="specifyInput" type="text" size="20" placeholder="specify" class="formfield3"/>
```

Then in javascript

```
function changeFUnction(ctrl)
{
    if(ctrl.value==2)
       {
           //Hide - display
       }
     else
       {
           //Hide display
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `onchange` event:

JavaScript:

```
var city = document.getElementById("city"),
    specify = document.getElementById("specify");

city.onchange = function(){
    if(city.value == 1) 
        specify.style.display = "none";
    else 
        specify.style.display = "inline";
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GaurangTandon/kfcyQ/3/)

Answer (score -1):

call a function on change and add id to input:

```
<select onchange="changeFUnction()">
    <option id="delhi" value="1"> Delhi </option>

    <option id="other" value="2"> - - other - -</option>
</select>

<input id="specifyInput" type="text" size="20" placeholder="specify" class="formfield3"/>
```

javascript:

```
function changeFUnction()
{
    if(city.value=="2")
       specifyInput.style["visibility"]="visible";
    else
       specifyInput.style["visibility"]="hidden";

}
```